# How to Create an org.reactivestreams.Publisher<ByteBuffer> from a java.io.InputStream?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, inputstream, bytebuffer, reactive-streams

**How can an `org.reactivestreams.Publisher<ByteBuffer>` be created from a `java.io.InputStream`?**

Context: I am using the awssdk to create an [`AsyncRequestBody`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html), I have an InputStream and am therefore trying to use the `AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher` method since none of the other "from" methods match.

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945665/get-an-publisherbytebuffer-from-inputstream) but it seems like the true issue in that question is related to mongo (based on the answer); my question is a broader reactive streams issue.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: You should be able to use something like Akka Streams' StreamConverters (https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/StreamConverters$.html#fromInputStream(in:()=%3Ejava.io.InputStream,chunkSize:Int):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]])  + `.map(_.asByteBuffer).runWith(Sink.asPublisher))`